# set property in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hi im trying to set a property in masterviewcontoller that belongs to another viewcontroller but it wont step into the set method. I have done this with the Masterviewcontroller to Detailviewcontroller and it works fine. now i copy that code and trying to do the same with masterviewcontroller to a controller named AddNoteViewController. same code but it wont step into the set method.
I have importet both classes the same
Thank you for your help!

**in debugging this works**

Step 1 masterviewController.m

```
//MasterViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
NSDate *kundnr = _kundnr[indexPath.row];
self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
self.detailViewController.detailIdentity = kundnr;
self.addNoteViewController.AddNoteFtgnr = kundnr;

}
```

Step2 DetailViewController.h

```
//DetailViewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailIdentity;
```

Step 3 DetailViewController.m

```
//DetailViewController.m
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}

if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}        
}

- (void)setDetailIdentity:(id)newDetailItentity
{
if (_detailIdentity != newDetailItentity) {
    _detailIdentity = newDetailItentity;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}

if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
}
```

**Now the AddNoteviewController that not works**

Step 1 masterviewController.m **(this is ok i think)**

```
//MasterViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
NSDate *kundnr = _kundnr[indexPath.row];
self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
self.detailViewController.detailIdentity = kundnr;
self.addNoteViewController.AddNoteFtgnr = kundnr;

}
```

Step 2 AddNoteViewController.h **(this is ok i think)**

```
//AddNoteViewController.h
@interface AddNoteViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id AddNoteFtgnr;
@end
```

Step 3 AddNoteViewController.m **(This is where the error is it don't step in here at all)**

```
//AddNoteViewController.m
-(void)setAddNoteFtgnr:(id)AddNoteFtgnr
{

//Code that sets the property

}
```

Comment: did you initialise `addNoteViewController` anywhere in `masterviewController`?

Comment: i did an #import in .m and in .h i did class AddViewController; and a property exaxtly the same as i did for the detailview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

In MasterviewController i have to init the viewcontroller that didnt happen.

```
AddNoteViewController* addNoteViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addNoteViewController"];

addNoteViewController.addNoteFtgNr = kundnr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your master view controller's detailViewController property is probably nil. Set a breakpoint in your `tableview:didSelectIndexPath:` method and examine the detailViewController property. If you don't know how to set breakpoints, then add an NSLog statement at the beginning of the method that displays the value in self.detailViewController. (And learn about breakpoints.)

Comment: yes i know how to set breakpoints and whats happen when i debugging have i explained. And its not the master -> detail that is the problem it's the master to AddNoteViewController and detail -> AddNoteView controller doesent work either i tried that to

Comment: If your setter is not  being called then either you have the name of the setter defined incorrectly, or your addNoteViewController property in your master view controller is nil.

Comment: One thing that is wrong: Property names should start with a lower case letter, and you should set them using code like `self.addNoteViewController.dddNoteFtgnr = kundnr;`. However, a custom setter method should be defined like `-(void)setAddNoteFtgnr:(id)addNoteFtgnr`, where the name of the method starts with the word 'set', and then the first letter of the property name is switched to a capital letter. I don't know if this is the cause of the problem or not, but it is wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: I deleted my code and coded it again with lowcase this time. Looking closely when debugging, after setting the property in masterviewcontroller.m it goes directly to masterviewcontroller.h and the code @property (strong,nonatomic) AddNoteViewController *addNoteViewController; then it goes straight back to masterViewController.m and does nothing more. I tried to set the property in viewdidload in my AddNoteViewController that woks fine.